# How to use graphql-request's batching via the batchRequests() function in redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, redux-saga, prisma, prisma-graphql

Here's how you can batch `graphql-requests`' using the `batchRequests` function in `redux-saga`.

```
export default ({ gqlClient } = {}) => {
function* getDashboardData() {
while (true) {
    try {
        yield take(dashboardActions.getDashboardDataPending.type);

        yield call([gqlClient, gqlClient.batchRequests],
           [{ document: queries.home.getUserData, variables: { period: 'day', date: 'last30' } },
            { document: queries.home.getRevenueData, variables: { period: 'day', date: 'last60' } }]
         );
         
         ...
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Answer lies in the question.